# Django / Postgres write-only database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

For a specific security reason, a client has asked if we can integrate a 'write-only' DB into a Django web application. I have tried creating a DB then restricting access to one of its tables in psql via:

```
REVOKE SELECT ON TABLE testapp_testmodel FROM writeonlyuser;
```

But then trying to save a model in the Django shell...

```
p = new TestModel(test_field="testvalue")
p.save(using="writeonlydb")
```

...generates this error:

```
ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation testapp_testmodel
```

Which I assume is because the ORM generated SQL includes a return of the newly created object's id, which counts as a read:

```
INSERT INTO "testapp_testmodel" ("test_field") VALUES ('testvalue') RETURNING "testapp_testmodel"."id"
```

My question is therefore, is this basically impossible? Or is there perhaps some other way?

Comment: What does your client expect this to achieve exactly?

Comment: Saving a new instance will do a read in order to retrieve the primary key value.

Comment: Make a schema the client can't access. Create functions with security definer to write into tables there.

Comment: I don't think django's ORM is designed with this scenario in mind. You might consider using psycopg to write directly to the secret postgres database instead.

Comment: You can always execute raw sql directly: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly . Django seems overkill. Maybe a lighter framework is a better match. Like Pyramid with SQLAlchemy.